# Why is scanf_s not working properly in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, scanf

What is the problem with the `scanf_s` call in my code? (I can't get the value into `num2` and the command is ending before it reaches the end.)

I don't have this problem when I try to do this:

```
scanf_s("%c", &op);
scanf_s("%d%d", &num1,&num2);
```

The original code:

```
#include<stdio.h>    
void main()
{
    int num1, num2, res, opok=1;
    char op;
    printf("please insert your experession:\n");
    scanf_s("%d%c%d", &num1, &op, &num2);
    
    switch (op)
    {
    case '+':
        res = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case '-':
        res = num1 - num2;
        break;
    case '*':
        res = num1 * num2;
        break;
    default:
        opok = 0;
        break;
    }
    if (opok == 1)
    {
        printf_s("%d\n", res);
    }
    else
    {
        printf_s("error\n");
    }

    

}
```

Comment: While it is likely the issue is you need to include a space in the `scanf_s` format string or to use proper arguments with it, how can anybody be sure? You did not provide the input you are typing, the resulting observed behavior of the program, or a description of what behavior you desired or expected instead. E.g., you did not tell us what values appear in `num1`, `op`, or `num2` after scanning or what values you expected to appear. In the future, when asking questions like this, include a [mre], including information about input, observed output, and desired output.

Comment: There is no such thing as "void main()". Please use one of the defined main function signatures. You probably want " int main()".

Comment: @EricPostpischil The documentation for `scanf_s`, whether in its [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) or [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) form, makes it clear what the issue is here.

Comment: @AdrianMole: The documentation for `scanf_s` makes it clear what **one** issue is. It does not make it clear that is OP’s only problem or even that it is the one causing whatever problem they are complaining about, which they failed to state completely. An MRE should always be provided with questions like this.

Comment: @nvoigt: C implementations are permitted to accept `void main()`, and, if you want to stick to one of the forms the standard requires that implementations accept, it would be `int main(void)`, not `int main()`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK, I see your point. (And there is also the issue of why the first code seems to work, I guess.)

Comment: @Eric Also, the code supplied by the OP (the main code) ***is*** an MRE! I copy/pasted it into my IDE (Visual Studio) without change and it compiled, ran and reproduced the problem.

Comment: @AdrianMole: An MRE is not just code that runs. It includes sample input, sample output, and desired output.

Comment: @EricPostpischil since you started being pedantic, the standard explicitly mentions `int main()` being acceptable, though *obsolescent*, allowed but discouraged. Most notably the C11,C17 drafts still use `int main()` in some of its examples.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: In the C 2018 standard, I see no explicit statement that `int main()` is acceptable and no statement that it is obsolescent. Please give specific citations.

Comment: there is no explicit citation, but there are still 2 examples that use `int main()`, and the standard says that the function should be defined to take no parameters, and `int main() {}` defines such a function too, though the example under uses `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 2):

When using the [`scanf_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) function, the `%c` and `%s` format specifiers require an additional *size* argument for each of their corresponding *data* arguments, which is the size of the buffer pointed to by that argument. This size argument (of unsigned type) should *immediately follow* the corresponding data argument.

In your case (a single character to be read with the `%c` format), the size of that buffer will be `1`, so use the following input line:

```c
scanf_s("%d%c%d", &num1, &op, 1u, &num2);
//                            ^ size of the "op" variable (in bytes)
```

Comment: Indeed, @roish the compiler should warn about this.